# How can I input a whole number less than 100 as a character array of digits and output the number in its word form as a string in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, io, character

I would like to create a C program that asks the user to enter a number less than 100 then output it in its word form. For example, the input may be '53' and I would like the output to be 'fifty three'. And if the input is a number equal to or greater than 100 (a string length >= 3) I would like the output to be an error message. Example: input is '132' and output is 'error: number is greater than or equal to 100'.
I've used a geeksforgeeks ( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/ )article as a guide since the tutorial accounts for numbers less than 10000, but I would like to only account for numbers less than 100.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convertnumtostring(char *num){
    int len = strlen(num);
    if(len==0){
        fprintf(stderr, "empty string\n");
        return;
    }
    if(len>2){
        fprintf(stderr, "number is is equal to or greater than 100\n");
        return;
    }

    char *singledig[]={"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    char *doubledig[]={"", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
    char *multiplesoften[]={"", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
        
    printf("\n%s: ", num);
    if(len==1){
        printf("%s\n", singledig[*num - '0']);
        return;
    }
        
    while(*num != '0'){
        if(*num == '1'){
            int sum = *num - '0' + *(num + 1)- '0';
            printf("%s\n", doubledig[sum]);
            return;
        } else if(*num == '2' && *(num + 1) == '0'){
            printf("twenty\n");
            return;
        } else {
            int i = *num - '0';
            printf("%s ", i? multiplesoften[i]: "");
            ++num;
            if(*num != '0')
                printf("%s ", singledig[*num - '0']);
        }
        ++num;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char input[10];
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    convertnumtostring(input);
    return 0;   

}
```

The code works as I would like it for numbers greater than 99/string lengths greater than 3 (100, 1313, 13235, etc.) because they recieve my desired error message and for the numbers 0-20 the proper word form is outputted (zero, four, twenty, etc.) but for all other numbers 21-99 I get a message saying

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I would like to know what the segmentation fault is and where/why it occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: `while(*num != '0')` should be `while(*num != '\0')`

Comment: Why do you need that loop at all?

Comment: I'm not entirely too sure, I just used the geeksforgeeks article as a template although I tested it out just now and it works without it. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Comment: You might need a loop to allow numbers of any length, but you don't need it when you only allow 1 and 2 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is an assignment, anyway, you should not manage code you can't read.
But I'll try to understand you.

First of all, you will find that segmentation fault problems are commonly associated to arrays.
It is caused by an illegal attemp to access some memory location, in this case the program tries to read a memory position beyond the some of the arrays.

Now, why does it happen in your program? Let's examine and comment the conflictive part of it:

```
while (*num != '0')
{
    if (*num == '1')
    {
        int sum = *num - '0' + *(num + 1) - '0';
        printf("%s\n", doubledig[sum]);
        return;
    } else if (*num == '2' && *(num + 1) == '0')
    {
        printf("twenty\n");
        return;
    } else
    {
        int i = *num - '0';                         //index ascii offset
        printf("%s ", i ? multiplesoften[i] : "");  //again compares if i is not 0
        ++num;                                      //next digit
        if (*num != '0')                            //is not equal to zero
            printf("%s ", singledig[*num - '0']);   //get by index ascii offset
    }
    
    ++num;//next digit again??? change ++num to break !!!

}
```

As you can see, once it has printed the number it continues the loop. This way the new digit will be garbage data, that data will be used to retrieve a string from your arrays using it as an index and that is what causes the segfault.

I hope my explanation can help you to continue your C learning.

Comment: This is in fact for an assignment for an online class. It's hard to manage and learn a language when the instructor only offers 2 hours of review every week for a 7 week course so I'm trying to utilize whatever online resources and forums I can to bridge the gap. As Barmar pointed out, the while loop is unnecessary and the last ++num; is redundant. Thank you for your response that does shed some light on how arrays and memory access work.

Comment: Beware his response "while(*num != '0') should be while(*num != '\0')".
It is OK being as it is because you are cheking if the second digit is indeed a zero, not a null character, deciding if you have to print the single digit array.
I know how you feel with that course. Be patient and don't hesitate to ask for help here.